# \section* no longer hides the section number

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, starred-version

I wanted to add a background color to my sections, but by doing so `\section*` no longer works properly, ie, it now shows the section number when I want to hide it. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[uppercase]{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcase}
\newcommand{\ColorSection}[1]{%
    \colorbox{red}{\parbox[c][1.5em][c]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
    {\MakeUppercase{\thesection\ #1}}}}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\titleformat{\section}
    {\sffamily\Large\raggedright}                                                
    {}{0pt}{\ColorSection}                                                      


\begin{document}

\section{with section number}

\section*{no section number}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a slightly different approach where you do not need to duplicate the formatting code.  The idea is to save the section number in a private macro, but make sure this is empty when appropriate.  I have also corrected a number points in your code:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\sstrut}{\vrule width 0pt height 14pt depth 4pt}
\newcommand{\ColorSection}[1]{%
    \colorbox{red}{\parbox[c]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
    {\raggedright\sstrut\MakeUppercase{\myslabel #1}\sstrut}}}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip} 

\titleformat{\section}{\gdef\myslabel{}\sffamily\Large}
{\gdef\myslabel{\thesection\ }}{0pt}{\ColorSection}                             

\begin{document}

\section{with section number}

\section*{no section number}

\section{long section title to demonstrate line wrapping}

\end{document}
```

- I have moved `\raggedright` into your `\parbox`.  Where it was placed it was having no effect and should have been `\filright` anyway.
- The specification of the `\parbox` with a fixed height is not good for long titles.  Instead I have placed special struts before and after the text making sure the box extends enough above and below.

Comment: +1, and should be accepted instead of my quick fix.

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[uppercase]{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcase}
\newcommand{\ColorSection}[1]{%
    \colorbox{red}{\parbox[c][1.5em][c]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
    {\MakeUppercase{\thesection\ #1}}}}
\newcommand{\ColorSectionStarred}[1]{%
    \colorbox{red}{\parbox[c][1.5em][c]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
    {\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\titleformat{\section}
    {\sffamily\Large\raggedright}                                                
    {}{0pt}{\ColorSection}     

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
    {\sffamily\Large\raggedright}                                                
    {}{0pt}{\ColorSectionStarred}                                                      

\begin{document}

\section{with section number}

\section*{no section number}

\end{document}
```

[image]